# How to get the value of a control that's bound to a binding source in VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, data-binding

I have a Dialog which has a ComboBox (`aComboBox`, say) with the following properties set:

- `DataSource` linked to a `BindingSource` which is linked to an SQL table
- `DisplayMember` linked to a column in that table which is of type `String`

Here is a pic of how the properties are set:

[image]

I want the `String` value of the item selected in the combo box but I am getting `System.Data.DataRowView`when I use this code at run time:

`aComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`

How do I get the String value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by setting the `Value Member` attribute as shown in the following image, I am then able to retrieve the String value by calling `aComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()` :

[image]

**Note:** Before, I only had the `Display Member` attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `aComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Instead of that Use : `aComboBox.SelectedValue()`

Comment: I tried this - the compiler is saying Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'

Comment: Chek `Data Binding` property of ComboBox in Properties window and Set Text value to NULL.

And then try

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I have edited my question with a picture of how the properties are set

Comment: after looking at your image, it looks like you don't have a DataBound ComboBox. Did you hard coded the connectivity ?

Comment: How do you mean hard coded? The combo box is bound via the DataSource and DisplayMember properties?

Comment: I mean to say, How did you do that ? If it isn't hardCoded, `Data Binding` must be shown in that image.